# responsive not working

Tags: responsive

I have responsive.css file, but the site is not responsive. I use bootstrap3 although I use the meta tag

when I minimize the browser to the size of tablet or mobile, responsive not working

even the nav menu links appears with the toggle button at the same time when I minimize the browser and all sections do not appear responsive.

please, what could be wrong?

Comment: What's responsive.css - is it a specific library, or do you mean you have written your CSS to be responsive, i.e. with @media selectors? Doesn't bootstrap already provide these, though, with the sm md lg versions of the width classes?

Comment: But chances are we can't really help you without seeing some of your code. Can you show us some of the code you've written that should be responsive but isn't?

Comment: @Rup thanks for your comment. it is html template I am converting to wordpress. I am sure it works well as html but after converting to wordpress everything is good but the responsive no longer working. yes responsive.css has all the responsive media codes. it is the same when we can put the responsive codes in style.css but here is we put on another file which is responsive.css

Comment: If you're generating the same HTML and you're loading the same CSS then it shouldn't really matter whether WordPress is involved or not. Unless I suppose there's a script error somewhere that's tripping up some code you're relying on. Have you checked your browser's debug console? Make sure that the responsive.css is loaded correctly, and that there are no script errors.

Comment: yes I have checked them, but no script errors